# Compare field (string) at $match stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to get the expected result with something like the following query.
I know that `$where` cannot be used in `$match`.

How should I compare the each field of string at `$match` stage?

***query***

```
db.col_sample.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$array"},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "col_population",
        localField: "array",
        foreignField: "foo.key",
        as: "join"
    }},
    {$match: {
        "join.foo.key2": "foo.key3"
    }}
])
```

***expected result***

```
{
  "_id": (snip),
  "foo": {
    "key1": "0xBBB",
    "key2": "bbb",
    "key3": "ccc"
  },  
  "array": [
    "0xCCC",
    "0xDDD"
  ]
}
```

***col_population***

```
{ 
  "foo": {
    "key1": "0xBBB",
    "key2": "bbb",
    "key3": "ccc"
  },  
  "array": [
    "0xCCC",
    "0xDDD"
  ]
}
{ 
  "foo": {
    "key1": "0xCCC",
    "key2": "ccc",
    "key3": "ddd"
  },  
  "array": [
    "0xDDD",
    "0xEEE"
  ]
}
```

***col_sample***

```
{ 
  "foo": {
    "key1": "0xAAA",
    "key2": "aaa",
    "key3": "bbb"
  },  
  "array": [
    "0xBBB",
    "0xCCC"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** pipeline instead of **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** as follows:

```
db.col_sample.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$array"},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "col_population",
        localField: "array",
        foreignField: "foo.key1",
        as: "join"
    }},
    {$unwind: "$join"},
    {$redact: {
        $cond: [
            { $eq: [ "$join.foo.key2", "$foo.key3" ] }, /// typo s/sjoin/join/
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```